# How to allow users to add/edit spry widgets

Tags: javascript, html, dreamweaver, spry

Creating a navigation tool where end users can locate certain points in a PDF by using a multitude of spry accordions/tabbed panels.

These pdfs are updated regularly meaning the navigation will have to get updated accordingly(no pun intended)

Users who will wish to maintain this navigation tool have little to no skill in building said sprys.

Could anyone point me in the right direction in how it is possible to allow these sprys to be edited easier by the users who will maintain them? Possibly a simple add/edit button?

Comment: i would have them edit plain html markup, and then turn that markup into your widget. Bootstrap does this very well. so well in fact, you never need to write custom JS to use their components. I'm not sure if spry is "declarative configured" like BS, but even if it's not, you can do the same thing by using jQuery to find (and hide) the semantic user-editable html, and feed that to your spry widget config, whatever form that might take.

Answer (score 0):

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/14167

This helped me loads if anyone else is looking for this question to be answered